# Why does my PHPUnit Fixtures Stack test is not working properly?

Tags: php, phpunit, fixtures

I've been reading [this](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html) manual, but I'm not understanding why the $stack loose the values after each test function.

Here's my code:

```
require_once BASE . 'Transaction.php';

class TransactionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $stack;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        Database::getInstance()->connect();
        $this->stack = new Transaction(123456789);
    }

    public function testInsert()
    {
        $data['name'] = 'Omega';
        $this->stack->set($data);
        $this->assertTrue($this->stack->save());
    }

    public function testUpdate()
    {
        $object = PHPUnitReflectionClass::getInstance($this->stack);
        $this->assertEquals(array('name' , 'Omega'), $object->getProperty('name'));
    }
}
```

At the "testUpdate" function, I don't have the name.

If I just copy all the PHPUnit example, all tests will run perfectly, but I'm not able to see the values using var_dump at the next function. And this is another thing that I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are:

1. the setup method is called before each test method invocation;
2. your test are depends each other.

For the **first problem** you can use the `setUpBeforeClass` method. From the [doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html):

> The setUp() and tearDown() template methods are run once for each test
>   method (and on fresh instances) of the test case class.
>
> In addition, the setUpBeforeClass() and tearDownAfterClass() template
>   methods are called before the first test of the test case class is run
>   and after the last test of the test case class is run, respectively.

For the **second problem**, is a bad practice to have tests that depends each otherbut PHPUnit supports the declaration of explicit dependencies between test methods, so you can use the `@depends` annotation to express dependencies: if a test fail the other is not executed.

So your test class can be, as example:

```
require_once BASE . 'Transaction.php';

class TransactionTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected static $stack;

     public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        Database::getInstance()->connect();
        $this->stack = new Transaction(123456789);
    }

    public function testInsert()
    {
        $data['name'] = 'Omega';
        $this->stack->set($data);
        $this->assertTrue($this->stack->save());
    }


   /**
    * @depends testInsert
    */
    public function testUpdate()
    {
        $object = PHPUnitReflectionClass::getInstance($this->stack);
        $this->assertEquals(array('name' , 'Omega'), $object->getProperty('name'));
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should *not* depend on other tests, it's considered bad practice. The point of unit tests is that they run in a controlled and isolated environment. The `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods are called respectively before and after *each* test method. And thus your `$stack` property is overwritten before each test. This is also pointed out in the document you linked to (just below example 4.1):

*The `setUp()` and `tearDown()` template methods are run once for each test method (and on fresh instances) of the test case class.*

(You're also making the assumption that the methods in your test class are run in the same order that they are written, but that isn't necessarily the case. Most of the time they do run in the same order, but you can't depend on it.)

Comment: Got it! And you are right. But let's just suppose that what I'm doing will not kill the humanity. So, why does the manual works but not my code?

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to example 4.1. Take a good look at what is actually happening in each method and you'll see that each test is assuming that the `$stack` property is empty to start with, which is what happens by calling the `setUp()` method before each test.